# using /tmp partition instead tmp folder under root partition

Tags: partition, tmp

I’m very new on using Linux (Debian) and have following question.
I installed debian and during the process also created separate partition for /tmp.
How can I now make sure that server programs use that special partition /tmp instead of /tmp folder under /root partition?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/where-do-the-files-go-if-you-mount-a-drive-to-a-folder-that-already-contains-fil/41337#41337

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to just a `/tmp` folder under the `/` partition (seen a lot). But it your case, `/tmp` is not just a directory under the `/` partition, it's a seperate mount point (just like `/` is the root mountpoint).

In other words, the `/tmp` you see is not a sub-directory of `/`, it's a seperate partition on your hard disk that can just be accessed through this path. You can see it as a sort of shortcut to that part on your harddisk. Filling up the `/tmp` will not affect the disk space usage of your `/` partition.

If you run `cat /etc/fstab` (which is the filesystem table file, holding all of your partition data) you can check out what your partitions are configured like and you should see `/tmp` as a seperate line.

Comment: Thank you for quick answere, doing cat /etc/fstab gave this output: proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/md0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md2 / ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md3 /tmp ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md4 /vz ext3 defaults 0 0

Comment: The line `/tmp ext3 defaults 0 0` means that `/tmp` is indeed a seperate partition, so every application will use that partition and won't fill up your primary partition.

Comment: OK, so programs will use that partition by default without me needing to edit anything? thank you for clearing it!